miter angle for glass pyramid
I am having trouble finding an important calculation while building a square pyramid out of glass. My pyramid will have a base edge length of 48 inches and slant height of 66.5 inches, side edge length of 70 inches which will make this pyramid approx 62 inches. I believe my side face angle to be 68.8 degrees. My question is: What would my face to face angle be? thank you so much!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Alice, from your post on Home Improvement, the 97 degree angle is correct  and is $ \arccos \frac{-576}{4324}  ,$   meaning the angle with cosine equal to the $\frac{-576}{4324}  .$   It is about 97.65 degrees. Note $24^2 = 576 $ and $70^2 - 24^2 = 4324$ Still, I recommend you get some thin cardboard or stiff paper and some tape,  and build your pyramid. Try it with measurements 70 millimeters and 48 millimeters,  or maybe double that for  140 and 96 mm.

You might like this better: the angle with cosine equal to $\frac{576}{4324}$   is about $ 82.35^\circ$   Subtract that from $180^\circ$  to get  $97.65^\circ$

@WillJagy Yes! This is the same answer I finally got by actually drawing it out. Everyone else were off and you nailed it, thank you!!!

given the weight of glass of that size, I suggest making a model in wood, five pieces including the exact miter angles. I worked (50 years ago) at a place that got in flat wood at about 3/8 of an inch thick, I'm holding a Platonic solid I made that way (dodecahedron). But I just chamfered all the edges  with a standard $45^\circ$ bit on the router, I did not do the more difficult  mitering you plan.  Extra thought:  you could make a glass model  perfect in every detail but no more than a foot high, just to practice the angles
